# My kitten licks me constantly, should I be worried?

Tags: cats, behavior, adoption, stress

I got a 12 week old kitten about two weeks ago, he seems like he's settled in nicely. (He's always sitting around me, when I'm home), but he's constantly licking me every time he's near me, like every-time (for several minutes at a time).

I've heard in the grapevine of pet owners, that it could be something to do with anxiety? Is this true, should I be worried? Or is he just trying to be playful i.e. a kitten's version of a pet? I'm quite new to owning a kitten, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to worry about, it's just because he extra loves you, and wants you to smell like him and be his.

When you see him licking **himself** a-lot, that could be a sign of anxiety. But if you're sure he likes your place and feels at home, then no worries, he just loves to see you back and that's how he expresses it.

It's not a play move by the way, it's showing affection. But I'd like to mention that he may feel lonely when you're not around and that gives him the reason to lick you a-lot. He feels very happy to see you there at last. Someone to play with and to be with. Kittens hate being alone. It's always better to get two kittens instead of one. After all they are kittens and they need a play mate almost all the time. So either be there for him 24/7 or get him a play mate, and you will see things change.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've been thinking of getting him a playmate. I might just do that and see how things improve.